# Where's my question gone?

Tags: support

I asked a question about The Six Sigma Illuminati and it's been deleted without trace, and I didn't even get a notification it was being removed.

Comment: It was deleted by the community as offensive.

Comment: The truth is often seen as such. It's an ongoing issue. You can trace it a long, long way back through history and see this pattern play out again and again.

Comment: Also, I'm not really asking for support as I don't really expect to get any here, it's more something of a bugbear.

Comment: So you're just trolling and/or ranting?  Knock it off.

Comment: What was your question?

Comment: @JimG. I was asking about why certain types of question had become the norm when all they seemed to be doing was helping rich people get richer. I made a joke about 'The Six Sigma Illuminati' to try to avoid outright offending people while still hoping it would garner the appropriate response. Which in this case was my suspension from the site, though I had of course hoped for a more amicable resolution similarly effective in drawing attention to the issue.

Comment: "The rich getting richer" was a thing years ago on Workplace.SE. I didn't know that it was still happening though. These days, I think people are actually earning their rep points.

Answer (score 18):

The question was not a real question but an attempt to use meta for personal amusement.  It was deleted as offensive by the community.

Comment: It wasn't a personal amusement, @MonicaCellio. I was using art to make a point about aspects of the site and the sort of questions which had become the norm, and were going unchallenged. I felt a less artistic response would have lacked the necessary emotional weight. I am aware this sort of "rocking the boat" is as almost universally unwelcome as it is often necessary.